# extjs editable grid - clear modified records list

Tags: extjs, grid

Hi
I have an editable grid. Some functions modify records in the grid. When a field value is changed, there is an onupdate event that fires.
The function that executes on update gets the modified record and checks which field was modified:

```
if (record.isModified('field1')) {...}
else if (record.isModified('field2')) {...}
```

The problem is that "isModified()" checks all the fields modified from the last load of the grid. Is there a way to clear the list or to get only the last modified field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the `getChanges()` method of `Record`? It returns the following (quotes from [ExtJS API documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.Record)):

> Gets a hash of only the fields that
>   have been modified since this Record
>   was created or commited.

Another option would be the `modified` property, which returns the following:

> This object contains a key and value
>   storing the original values of all
>   modified fields or is null if no
>   fields have been modified.

Comment: this is the problem: all these are returning the modified records/fields from the loading of the store or creting the record. In my case the grid is not connected to the database, so I need to know what is the last field been modified

Comment: Ok. What about calling `Record.commit()` after each change then? Calling commit resets the modified attribute of the record. This way, on every update the abovementioned methods would only return the last modification.

Comment: Also note that calling `commit()` will cause another `update` event to trigger, but with different `operation` value (`COMMIT` instead of `EDIT`). Examine the `operation` and do nothing if it is `COMMIT`.